# QT5.4 remove and delete widget in a layout

Tags: qt, qwidget, qt5.4, qlayout

I have a `QStackedLayout` which contains few `QWidget` on it. The widgets layout is `QVBoxLayout` which have also few `QPushButton`. What I wanted to do is to remove all the widgets inside the `QStackedLayout` and then delete the widgets and layouts **BUT** I want all the buttons not to be deleted 'cause I will put them to another widget later.

Here's my code:

```
while (QLayoutItem *item = m_stacked_layout->takeAt(0)) {
    QWidget *w = item->widget();

    for (int i = 0; i < w->layout()->count(); i++) {
        QPushButton *button = qobject_cast<QPushButton *>(w->layout()->itemAt(i)->widget());
        if (button) {
            w->layout()->removeWidget(button);
        }
    }

    delete w;
    delete item;
}
```

The application crashes at the line `delete w;`. And, if I remove the `delete` lines, application works fine.

Comment: The documentation for QLayoutItem suggests that QLayoutItem::widget() is more of a casting function than returning a member. Thus you shouldn't delete the widget separately from the item.

Comment: Does the widget also deleted when the QLayoutItem is deleted.

Comment: Won't work. When you add a widget to a layout, the layout takes ownership of the widget. Delete the layout and you delete the widget. removeWidget does not transfer the ownership back. So your buttons are deleted anyways.

Answer (score 1):

> BUT I want all the buttons not to be deleted 'cause I will put them to
>   another widget later.

1. Hide all widgets that you want to transfer
2. Set parent widget for all this widgets to `nullptr`
3. Later... set necessary parent and show widgets

Note: if you want to delete widgets inside some slots, you should use `deleteLater` method.

Comment: I replace `delete w` with `w->deleteLater()` and `w->layout()->removeWidget(button)` with `button->setParent(NULL)`, and it works fine now. As I read about `deleteLater`, the object will be deleted once the event loop exited. Is there other way to delete the widget immediately? BTW, the code above was called in `resizeEvent`

Comment: Not when event loop is exited. But when it continue. You may read Qt documentation about `deleteLater` + when and why it should be used. In most casts you may delete widgets immediately with delete operator.